# Silverlight page content size based on browser size

Tags: .net, silverlight, xaml

What i have got is a Page class that contains:

```
<navigation:Page (...) Title="Import">
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
                  HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                  Visibility="{Binding Visible}">
        <c:BusyIndicator IsBusy="{Binding Busy}">
            <StackPanel>
                <StackPanel>
                    <Button/>
                </StackPanel>
                <Border Background="#c8c8c8" CornerRadius="5">
                    <sdk:DataGrid Name="myDataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                                  ItemsSource="{Binding Imports}" Margin="10" IsReadOnly="True">
                        <sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
                            <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Header="ID" Binding="{Binding ID}" Width=".3*"/>
                            <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}" Width=".7*"/>
                        </sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
                    </sdk:DataGrid>
                </Border>
            </StackPanel>
        </c:BusyIndicator>
    </ScrollViewer>        
</Grid>
</navigation:Page>
```

What I try to accomplish is that DataGird will always have max possible width and height. It also should have min width and height fixed. When browser is smaller than DataGrid, ScrollViewer should enable srolling. I thought that Min/Max Width/Height properties will allow this behavior but i am not able to get it working.

Answer (score 0):

Need change markup a litle.

StackPanel grow to its entire content and prevent scrollbar make visible.
Grid element overlap content if you set one value in Grid.Row. It's useful when you set busyindicator above content.

```
<navigation:Page xmlns:sdk="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/sdk"  x:Class="SilverlightApplication1.Page1" 
       xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
       xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
       xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
       xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
       mc:Ignorable="d"
       xmlns:navigation="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Navigation"
             xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Toolkit" d:DesignWidth="640" d:DesignHeight="480"
       Title="Page1 Page">
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition MinHeight="150"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Button Grid.Row="0"/>
        <Border Grid.Row="1" Background="#c8c8c8" CornerRadius="5">
            <sdk:DataGrid Name="myDataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                                  ItemsSource="{Binding Imports}" Margin="10" IsReadOnly="True">
                <sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
                    <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Header="ID" Binding="{Binding ID}" Width=".3*"/>
                    <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}" Width=".7*"/>
                </sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
            </sdk:DataGrid>
        </Border>
    </Grid>
    <Controls:BusyIndicator IsBusy="{Binding Busy}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
</Grid></navigation:Page>
```